# How could I go about finding the weights or importance of inputs based on outputs?

Tags: machine-learning, python, data, data-analysis

I have a table who's inputs (`sfm`, `fr`, and `doc`) all affect the outputs (`mmr` and `ra`). How could I go about finding the input importance on the outputs? Basically, I'd like to be able to have a goal output in `mmr` and `ra` and have a good idea of starting parameters for `sfm`, `fr`, and `doc`. Does anyone have insight into something like this? Below is a sample of the data.

```
sfm    fr    doc    mmr      ra

60     0.15  0.1    449.6    1.85
60     0.15  0.2    896.78   0.86
60     0.15  0.25   1116.34  1.28
60     0.2   0.1    593.46   1.42
60     0.2   0.2    1183.62  0.91
60     0.2   0.25   1473.34  1.91
60     0.25  0.1    734.26   1.59
60     0.25  0.2    1464.41  1.52
60     0.25  0.25   1822.79  1.07
70     0.15  0.1    503.3    1.42
70     0.15  0.2    1003.74  0.89
70     0.15  0.25   750.31   0.99
70     0.2   0.1    665.35   1.12
70     0.2   0.2    1326.9   1.96
70     0.2   0.25   1651.5   1.73
70     0.25  0.1    822.97   0.99
70     0.25  0.2    1641.19  1.17
70     0.25  0.25   2042.57  0.85
```

Comment: I think you want a [reverse] prediction from x:(mmr, ra) to y:(sfm, fr, doc)? you what a y for a given x?

Comment: Yes, exactly! I'll collect data points in the real world as the basis, but I can't test every possible outcome, so I'd like to know how I can figure out the "ideal" inputs from target outputs based on this collected data

Comment: This can be done we a standard neural network that has 2 dimensional input  for (mmr, a) and 3 dimensional output for (sfm, fr, doc), done! After model is trained, you input an arbitrary (mmr, a) and it gives (sfm, fr, doc). If it works let me know to put it into an answer

Comment: Yes, I've been fooling around with that a little, unfortunately it's not yielding great results (and by not great I mean not even in the ballpark). Would you have any suggestion as to the type of neural net? CNN, RNN, LSTM, etc? Or attributes?

Comment: Did you calculate the correlation between each of the input columns and the outputs?

Comment: @AlirezaZolanvari I can calculate them, but I do not know what to do with them: relative to `mrr` -  sfm    0.079940, fr     0.553807, doc    0.764792, mrr    1.000000 and relative to `ra` - sfm   -0.193601, fr    -0.018381, doc   -0.133166, ra     1.000000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pearson correlation can be used for this purpose. The Pearson correlation between two entity shows that how mush the values of these two are  linearly related to each other.

> According to the Cauchy–Schwarz inequality it has a value between +1
>   and −1, where 1 is total positive linear correlation, 0 is no linear
>   correlation, and −1 is total negative linear correlation.

According to the values you reported here, there is a strong correlation between `doc` and `mrr` so the role of `doc` in the prediction of `mrr` is more important than others.

But on the other hand none of the features doesn't have any considerable linear correlation with `ra`. In this case you can test some other correlation methods.

For further information visit [here](https://math.tutorvista.com/statistics/correlation.html). It can be helpful to you.

Conclusion: the most important feature in predicting an output is the most correlated one with it which has a considerable correlation.

Comment: I'll mark this as an accepted answer because you're trying to help. I really haven't gotten much further though. I do understand what you're saying of course, but without a practical example it is still grey. Thank you tho for trying